# Upload file at checkout

Tags: bigcommerce

Is it possible to add a input type=file element to the checkout.html and persist it as an attachment to a checkout?

It seems the only way to make a file attachment in an order that would be visible from the store admin is to create a file option https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Options-SKUs-Rules#file-upload, and add that to the cart to support the attachment.

Comment: You are right, at the moment that's the only option.

Comment: Mind if we ask your use case @JJS?

Comment: @KarenWhite I want to allow a customer paying with an offline method (Cash on Delivery renamed as purchase-order) to upload a file representing the purchase order. I want the admin viewing the order in the /manage/orders interface to have a link to the file without opening a new interface.

Comment: I'm aware of this addon in the store. https://www.intuitsolutions.net/bigcommerce-add-ons/purchase-order-solution-pdf-upload/ - my question is specifically about the OOTB capabilities of the store

Comment: @IgnacioCatalina thanks for the comment. Can you expand on this at all?

Comment: hey @JJS, I just meant natively. You can always install an app to enable those features, but it is not something bigcommerce supports out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the context @JJS! I wanted to mention that file upload field support is coming soon for the S2S Cart API--that could be helpful in this case.

Comment: @KarenWhite thank you. that's exciting news. Please make sure there's an announcment in the developer feed and/or the dev blog on medium

Comment: Will do! We'll keep you posted

Answer (score 0):

No, at this time it is not possible to add a input type=file element to the checkout.html and persist it as an attachment to a checkout.

### Current Options

**Apps**

- https://www.intuitsolutions.net/bigcommerce-add-ons/purchase-order-solution-pdf-upload/

**Product Option**

- File Upload Product Option - https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Options-SKUs-Rules#file-upload
  A file can be stored as an option-value on a product that is dynamically added to the cart.
  This would require effort in hiding the product that represents the purchase order from showing up in the cart and checkout.

**Future Options**

- file upload field support is coming soon for the S2S Cart API - thanks @KarenWhite
- True Purchase Order Support sometime in the future...